# Is it possible to parse two JSON objects in JavaScript that are back to back?

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible to parse a JSON object back to back in javascript? Under normal conditions, I am parsing a JSON object that looks like:

```
{"success":true, "canUpload":false, "array":[ ], "test": "value"}
```

and I have no problem with the above. However, I am wondering if I can parse two JSON library out there that is able to detect two JSON objects concatenated together? For example,

```
{"success":true, "canUpload":false, "array":[ ], "test": "value"}{"newJSONobj":"new value1"}
```

I'm expecting two JSON objects in the 2nd example.

Comment: You have bigger issues here: Why is your data 2 JSON strings concatenated?

Comment: JSON Object or String? You parse a string.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer - this is because I don't have access to source code of a COTS product and I'm trying to modify an HttpResponse, with new data, however, I cannot delete an HttpResponse body content and re-write it with my own.  So I'm trying to figure out a way to work with adding the data I need to the response, and then parse it appropriately in Javascript

Comment: Why not parse them separately and then merge them using jQuery or whatever other library.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - I think that is my only option, just wondering if there are any other options out there.

Comment: Then how are you adding that data? If you can add it, you can probably parse the existing response and merge in your response. If you can explain the entire case in your question, you'll get better answers faster.

Comment: If you are sure that they are both objects and that the keys will never overlap, then you can remove the enclosing `}` from the first object and then add a comma `,` and add to that the second object with the `{` removed from its begining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot if you are using web standards. If you have access to the source that creates that JSON string, format it correctly. You'll need to convert that into an array of two objects. You would have to separate those 2 objects with a comma, and then wrap those 2 objects in a bracket.

```
[{
    "success": true,
    "canUpload": false,
    "array": [],
    "test": "value"
}, {
    "newJSONobj": "new value1"
}]
```

If you don't have access to the source, then you'll have to use some javascript string manipulation to either break that out as 2 separate strings, or add in some additional characters to achieve the format listed above. This is a possible solution:

```
var jsonObjects = JSON.parse('[' + jsonString.replace(/\}\{/g, '},{') + ']');
```

This essentially wraps your two objects in brackets and separates the two objects with a comma (creating an array of 2 objects). *Please be aware, however, that this is not going to be 100% reliable. You may get data in other formats that this procedure can't handle correctly.*

Comment: The problem is I cannot do this because I don't have access to the source code for this COTS software, and since an HttpResponse (once written to) cannot be re-written, I am simply trying to work with the COTS and add the data I need to parse on the client-side

Answer (score 2):

You could just convert it to a JSON array by string operations. Like:

```
var objects = JSON.parse('[' + yourString.replace(/\}\{/g, '},{') + ']');
```

This would work in both cases (1 or more objects).

Comment: `/\}\s*\{/g` if there is spaces inbetween.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir You're right. There wasn't any in the example, but that would make it more robust.

Comment: + there will be a problem if one of the objects is an array.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir The question was about 2 objects.

Answer (score 0):

What you showed is not a valid json string(object), so you'd get error when you try to parse it. If the concatenated string is created by yourself instead of being passed over to you, you can create a string with two (or more) objects like the below. Then you'll get an array (an object itself) of two (or more) objects.

```
  '[{"success":true, "canUpload":false, "array":[ ], "test": "value},{"newJSONobj":"new value1"}]'
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a JSON String like so:

```
'{"success":true, "canUpload":false, "array":[ ], "test": "value"}{"newJSONobj":"new value1"}'
```

Then yes. You simply need to do just a little modding to it.

```
data = '{"success":true, "canUpload":false, "array":[ ], "test": "value"}{"newJSONobj":"new value1"}'
data.split(/(?!})(?={)/).map(function(v, i) { return JSON.parse(v); })
```

See?

```js
var data = '{"success":true, "canUpload":false, "array":[ ], "test": "value"}{"newJSONobj":"new value1"}';

var result = data.split(/(?!})(?={)/).map(function(v, i) { return JSON.parse(v); });

console.log(result)
```

```html
<h1><center>See Console</center><h1>
```